# Can I run Azure DevOps pipeline without committing it?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am planning to experiment building a pipeline using Azure DevOps. One thing that I noticed early on is, after `azure-pipelines.yml` created, I have to commit this first before being able to run it. But I want to experiment on it which revolves around trial and error. Doing multiple commit just to test things out are not feasible.

In Jenkins I can just define my steps and try to run it without committing the file.
Is this also possible to do in Azure DevOps?

Comment: Why do not you disable/limit the triggers of the pipeline on the commit? You can then make many commits and not trigger the pipeline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot run YAML pipelines without committing them, but you can create classic pipelines and run them without committing anything pipeline-related to the repository (except for the source code you want to build). Classic pipelines  can later be turned (or copy-pasted, to be exact) into yaml pipelines with *view YAML* -option.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/get-started/pipelines-get-started?view=azure-devops#define-pipelines-using-the-classic-interface

Answer (score 3):

> But I want to experiment on it which revolves around trial and error. Doing multiple commit just to test things out are not feasible.

Yes it is - you just use a different [code branch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/manage-your-branches?view=azure-devops). That will allow you the freedom to make as many changes as you need, while putting the pipeline together and trying it out, without committing to the *master* branch.
Then when you're happy with the way the pipeline is running, you can [merge your branch into the master branch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/pull-requests?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser) which the pipeline normally uses.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on your own branch, or in a repository without any other developers making changes then you can

1. Make a change
2. use `git commit --amend` to overwrite your previous commit with the new file
3. use `git push --force-with-lease` to push that up to Azure DevOps

That will hide your commit history while experimenting